# Can't change fontFace in Windows Terminal

Tags: json, powershell, windows-terminal

Trying out Windows Terminal customization via settings.json.  I found a profiles.json that follow the new conventions closely enough to work when pasted into settings.json, (I know it took because the theme changed).  The problem is that changes to "fontFace" are not having any effect.  I'm trying to use a nerd font for some powerline stuff, works in Powershell running in ConEmu but not in Windows Terminal.  Here is the relevant portion of settings.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

    "defaultProfile": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",

    // You can add more global application settings here.
    // To learn more about global settings, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-global-settings

    // If enabled, selections are automatically copied to your clipboard.
    "copyOnSelect": false,

    // If enabled, formatted data is also copied to your clipboard
    "copyFormatting": false,

    // A profile specifies a command to execute paired with information about how it should look and feel.
    // Each one of them will appear in the 'New Tab' dropdown,
    //   and can be invoked from the commandline with `wt.exe -p xxx`
    // To learn more about profiles, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-profile-settings
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
            "cursorShape": "vintage",
            "fontFace": "Iosevka Nerd Font"
        },
        "list":
        [
            {
                // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile.
                "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                "name": "Windows PowerShell",
                "commandline": "powershell.exe",
                "hidden": false,
                "fontFace": "Iosevka Nerd Font",
                "colorScheme": "PowerShellTom",
                "useAcrylic": true,
                "acrylicOpacity": 0.8
            },
            { ...
```

I get the same behavior in Windows Terminal Preview, which is supposed to be the least "bleeding edge" version.

Even trying non-nerd fonts for "fontFace" has no effect, however, "fontSize" will work.

Comment: What version of Windows Terminal are you using?

Comment: The about dialog gives the version as Version: 1.0.1401.0

Comment: for 'Windows Terminal Preview', (which has the same problem), it is Version: 1.1.1671.0

Comment: Created an issue for this Windows Terminal github page, got pointed to similar issues that involve only installing the font for current user rather than all users.  I'm playing with that but no joy yet.  Major pain as I used the install.ps included with the Nerd "patched fonts" folder to install all the nerd fonts, which it does for the current user.

Comment: I've found that there is a registry key for each of the Windows Terminal apps, (regular and Preview), Computer\HKEY_ ... \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe that has three entries, (default), Cascadia.tff, and CascadiaMono.ttf. The Value data , (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\CascadiaMono.ttf) leadl me to explore the containing folder, where two cascadia true type fonts are.  If I could get 'CascadiaMono PL', I believe it would work, but Windows 10 has that locked out.

Comment: I was able to use 'Cascadia Mono PL' by adding a registry string at the above registry path: Value name: CascadiaMonoPL.ttf Value data: C:\Users\tfeth\OneDrive\Documents\Fonts_Power_Line\CascadiaMonoPL.ttf.  Try something similar for Iosevka, no joy.

Comment: I installed `Iosevka Term Nerd Font Complete Windows Compatible.ttf` and had the same issue. Not working in windows Terminal but working in ConEMu (Cmder).

Comment: That is my experience also.  Also posting on Windows Terminal issue #6606

Comment: I think something is up with how `Isoveka NF` is crafted. Other NF fonts work in Windows terminal. Would you be open to using `MesloLGS NF` font? I use it in windows Terminal for all my powerline stuff (fancy glyphs, etc..)

Answer (score 40):

For people who are coming from [SCOTT HANSELMAN article (especially from the third step)](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-make-a-pretty-prompt-in-windows-terminal-with-powerline-nerd-fonts-cascadia-code-wsl-and-ohmyposh)

1. Install `Cascadia Code` for all users

[image]

2. Change the "fontFace" property in the settings.json like this 
   *Shortcut to open settings.json: Ctrl+Shift+, (comma)*

[image]

here is the code to copy

```json
"profiles": {
   "defaults": {
      "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL"
      // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
    }
}
```

---

This is the only way I made that work (after 2 hours or trying)

Comment: I had that issue with windows terminal. This answer solved my problem!

Comment: Odd that it's only the PL variant of the Cascadia Code that works on my laptop, and not the others as per the answer. I've tried the rest of them and they all show the rectangles.

Comment: Shortcut to open settings.json: Ctrl+Shift+, (comma)

Answer (score 4):

Change the fontFace from "Iosevka Nerd Font" to just "Iosevka"; the fontFace attribute expects a font *family*, as far as I'm aware this isn't in the documentation and I only found it out after reading [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6936) on the WT github

Answer (score 3):

From a comment to the Issue I opened on Windows Terminal's GitHub page, (#6606), I was directed to another fontFace problem where choosing another font would not stick if you reopened WT, (not quite the problem I was having).

Anyway, the current solution to that is to uninstall any font you want to use, then right-click and choose "Install for all users".  Double-click the file to open the sample view, and use the font name found just below the the two buttons. use the spaces in the font name as is in your settings.json file.

This worked for MesloLGL NF, but not Iosevka NF.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to install MesloLGS NF Regular as a recommended font for Powerlevel10k in WindowsTerminal for WSL:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/font.md

To make it work I had to:

1. Install it for all users as @hakan-fıstık showed in his answer.
2. Change the "fontFace" in settings.json to "MesloLGS NF" (Supplying full names of fonts is not working as supposed to).
3. Be sure to change size of font (changing font may make it huge): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-appearance

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, editing the 'settings.json' file manually creates more issues than it resolves. The easiest way to edit the default font of your terminal is as follows:

1. Open the settings
2. Select Ubuntu under the 'Profiles' header on the sidebar
3. Scroll down to 'Additional Settings' and select 'Appearance'
4. Under the text header, change the 'Font face' attribute to your preferred font
   [image]
5. Open 'settings.json' to view changes
6. You should see the expected format for selecting a font - Should you wish to edit the json file manually, you should follow this format
   [image]
7. Save changes and exit